# How to perform a command if image found using Imacros (IE)

Tags: if-statement, imacros

I know how to make Imacros search for an image, but my problem is, I want the imacros to search for an image and if found do this command, else do this command, I need the IF Statement to use in Imacros, I know it is available on Firefox, in a Javascript, but I cannot use Firefox, so what I basically want is:

ImageCheck, if found
DO THIS COMMAND
ELSE
DO THIS COMMAND

Answer (score 0):

That should go something like this. I see no way to use this on IE and no way why you shouldn't use it in FireFox. I don't know any other code that would work in IE since this can't be done without JavaScript.

```
   var macroSearchImage;

macroSearchImage ="CODE:";
macroSearchImage +="TAG POS=1 TYPE=IMG ATTR=HREF:www.somelink.com/image.png CONTENT=EVENT:MOUSEOVER"+"\n";



if(iimPlay(macroSearchImage)>0)
{
alert("image found");

//do something
}
else
{
alert("Image not found");

//do something
}


//end of the code
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but it says:
Error -1100: Unknown command: MACROSEARCHIMAGE at line: 1

Comment: Check again now. 1. Put it in the .js file and make sure that you place var macroSearchImage; on the beginning.